# Django ORM filter by group with where clause

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model of students and opinions. Each student can change their opinion over time. What I ultimately want to do is create a plot showing the number of students with each opinion on a given day, but as a first step I want to count the number of students with each opinion on a given day.

My model is as follows (abbreviated for brevity):

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)


class Opinion(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    opdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    sentiment_choice = [
    ('Positive', 'Positive'),
    ('Negative', 'Negative'),
    ]   
    sentiment = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        choices=sentiment_choice,
        default="Positive",
        null=True, blank=True
    )
```

My approach is to loop over all the dates in a range, filter the opinion table to get all the data upto that date, find the latest opinion per student, count these and load the results into an array.

I know how to filter the opinion table as follows (where start_date is my iterator):

```
Opinion.objects.filter(opdate__lte=start_date)
```

I also know how to pickup the latest opinion for each student:

```
 Opinion.objects.values('student').annotate(latest_date=Max('opdate'))
```

How would I combine this so that I can get the latest opinion for each student that is prior to my iterator?

I'm working on Django 3.2.12 with an SQL Lite DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [**`Subquery`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) with:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Student.objects.annotate(
    last_sentiment=Subquery(
        Opinion.objects.filter(
            student_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-opdate').values('sentiment')[:1]
    )
)
```

The `Student`s will have an extra attribute `.last_sentiment` that will contain the `sentiment` of the last related `Opinion` record, or `NULL`/`None` if there is no related `Opinion`.